# Jolt tranformation merge records

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

facing one issue with Jolt -

Current input -

```json
[
  {
    "test1": "A",
    "test2": "X",
    "test3": "Y",
    "test4": "Z"
  },
  {
    "test1": "B",
    "test2": "X",
    "test3": "Y",
    "test4": "Z"
  }
]
```

Output required is

```json
[
  {
    "test1": "A",
    "label": [
      {
        "test2": "X",
        "test3": "Y",
        "test4": "Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "test1": "B",
    "label": [
      {
        "test2": "X",
        "test3": "Y",
        "test4": "Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Basically to merge the three attributes under one and the rest one should be outside

Tried with below Jolt but not working -

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "test1": "&",
      "*": "row.&"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepend the values of the attributes other than `test1` by **`label[0]`** while distinguishing objects by prepending **`&1`** as the leading in order to substitute the indexes of them element such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "test1": "&1.&",
        "*": "&1.label[0].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site **http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/** is :

[image]